# How to make global arraylist using java, getting error "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

I'm still a beginner, trying to make a simple app that calls bingo numbers using java in android studio. I'm having trouble removing numbers once they have been called. I'm trying to make the array list public and accessible to my button method, but I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol 'ball'". I've tried placing the array list beneath `onCreate()`, but then I'm told I need to declare ball final. If I do that, I can't remove from the array list later. I've tried many different things but I can't seem to get it, any suggestions are appreciated!

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> ball = new ArrayList<String>();
    ball.add("B1");
    ball.add("B2");
    ball.add("B3");
    ball.add("B4");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random r = new Random();
            String call = ball.get(r.nextInt(ball.size()));
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            text.setText(call);
            ball.remove(r);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Your `onClick` doesn't have to contain all your code. You can have it call a method on an object that maintains the state of the bingo. The object could be created and initialized in `onCreate`, for example. There are many ways to do this, but modularizing your code early on and refactoring often is recommended even for trivial programs.

Comment: Public != global. There are no global a in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in android studio there is no need of the so called "main" function which is widely used on other java programs, as it has not by default the same usage. However, `onCreate()` method can be referred to be similar to the usage of `main` in general. The below code, addresses your problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private ArrayList<String> ball;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ball = new ArrayList<String>();

    ball.add("B1");
    ball.add("B2");
    ball.add("B3");
    ball.add("B4");


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random r = new Random();
            String call = ball.get(r.nextInt(ball.size()));
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            text.setText(call);
            ball.remove(r);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I strongly recommend you to go through the basics of android again, ideally starting from [Android Developers:Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Hope I helped,